# Example for strncpy()

Tags: c, string

If I would use the `strncpy` function for the strings `cat` and `dog`. I don't understand if the `\0` character is counted in or not, so I would like to know if the end result will be `catdo`? or would it be something like `cat\0do`

`strncpy("cat", "dog", 2);`

Comment: You can't do this. `"cat"` is a string literal, not a string. You cannot assign a new value to it, any more than you could do `4 = 5;`

Comment: Assuming `"cat"` was actually a pointer to a writable char array and not a string literal, that would set the first two elements to `'d'` and `'o'` and stop. Don't use `strncpy()`.

Comment: Why would you use that function at all?

Answer (score 1):

As torstenvl mentioned, `"cat"` and `"dog"` are string literals, so you're not using the function correctly here. The first parameter is the destination, the second parameter is the source, and the third parameter is the number of bytes to copy.

```
char *strncpy(char *restrict s1, const char *restrict s2, size_t n)
```

> Source: [The Open Group Base Specification - strncpy](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strncpy.html#top)

To answer your specific question: yes; the null terminator is copied to the destination string. `n` bytes are written, and if your source string `s2` is shorter than `n` bytes, `NULL` is filled in until `n` bytes are written.

In your question, it looks like you're trying to append the two strings. To do this in C, you need to first allocate a source string buffer, copy the first string over, then copy the second string, starting from the end of the second string. Depending on where you start the last step, you can end up with either "catdog\0" or "cat\0dog\0". This is another example of the quintessential "off by one" errors.

To start, you have to calculate the length of the two strings you want to append. You can do this using `strlen`, from `string.h`. `strlen` does **not** count the null-terminator as part of the length, so remember that to get the length of the final string, you'll have to do `strlen(s1) + strlen(s2) + 1`.

You can then copy the first string over as you normally would. An easy way to do the second copy is to do this:

```
char* s2start = finalString[strlen(s1) + 1];
```

You can then do `strncpy(s2start, s2, [the size of s2])` and that way you know you're starting right on the s1 null terminator, avoiding the "cat\0dog" error.

Hope this helps, good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use the `strncpy` and `strncat` functions at all.

Their names start with `str`, but they do not really work with strings. In C, a string is defined as "a character sequence terminated by `'\0'`". These functions do not guarantee that the resulting character array is always null-terminated.

The better alternatives are `strlcpy` and `strlcat`, but these are not available everywhere.

Even better would be a separate string library in which determining the length of a string were a constant-time operation. But that gets distracting.

Comment: `strncat` is much less problematic than `strncpy`, but I agree neither one should be used.

Answer (score 0):

When you write out a string like `"cat"` or `"dog"` in c, the arrays cannot be changed, if you try it will result in undefined behavior. You can only use these if a function expects `const char * input`, `const` is telling you that it cannot/will not be changed in the function. When you write `"dog"` the data in the character array will look something like this:

```
{'d','o','g','\0'}
```

Notice it is NUL terminated.

The function you are using:

```
char *strncpy(char *dest, const char *src, size_t n)
```

Copies `src` to `dst` with a maximum length of `n` you cannot copy into `"cat"` as mentioned above, you can see `char *dest` is not constant but `const char * src` is constant. So the source could be `"cat"` or `"dog"`

If you were to allocate space for the string you are allowed to modify it:

```
char cat_str[] = "cat";
```

now the character array `cat_str` is initialized to `"cat"` but we can alway change it, note its length will be 4 (one for each letter plus a NUL) because we did not specify the length. So be sure to not change anything past cat_str[3], you can index it by 0 to 3

Comment: I have to use it for college, I am also not hapoy about that I have to use it

Comment: This explanation lacks the main point about this function: **do not ever use `strncpy`**... even if you happen to know what it does, the next reader of your code might not and will be misled in thinking that it does something useful.

Answer (score 0):

There is a common misconception from some static analysis tools that `strncpy` is a safer version of `strcpy`. It's not, it has a differnt purpose.  If we insist on using it to prevent buffer overflows, you need to be cognisent of the fact that for it's signature

```
char * strncpy ( char * destination, const char * source, size_t num );
```

No null-character is implicitly appended at the end of `destination` if `source` is longer than `num`. Thus, in this case, `destination` shall not be considered a null terminated C string (reading it as such would overflow).

So if you know that your source is a null terminated C string, then you can do the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  const char* source = "dog";
  char destination[4] = "cat";

  printf("source is %s\n", source);
  printf("destination is %s\n", destination);

  /* the strlen+1 accounts for null termination on source */
  /* but you need to be sure that source can fit into destination */
  /* and still be null terminated - (that's on you the programmer) */
  strncpy(destination, source, strlen(source) + 1);

  printf("source is still %s\n", source);
  printf("destination is now %s\n", destination);

  return 0;
}
```